# Scrapy get objects from different pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy in python.
I am scraping 3 pages in a website that says A page, B page, C page.
First thing Ive done is that I got link from A page to go into B page.
Secondly, I got X and Y element in B page and also the link to C page where I need Z element.
But how do I gather X and Y in B page and Z in C page, and then put all three into like this:

```
yield {"X": X, "Y": Y, "Z": Z}
```

This is the code Ive tried so far, now I only got elements from B page but I dont know how to extract element from C page as well:

```
class exampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exampleSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/"]

# IN A PAGE:

    def parse(self, response):
        B_link = response.css("h3 a ::attr(href)").get()

        B_linkk = "https://www.example.com" + B_link

            yield response.follow(B_linkk, callback = self.parse_B_page)

# IN B PAGE:

    def parse_B_page(self, response):
        X = response.css('a span::text').get()
        Y = response.css('h1.p-title-value::text').get()

        yield {"X": X, "Y": Y}

# IN C PAGE:

    def parse_C_page(self, response):
```

Comment: Use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=cb_kwargs#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs).